# networkx - can't remove_node from graph

Tags: python-3.x, nodes, networkx

A `G = nx.DiGraph()` whose `nodes` and `edges` are the following:

```
G.nodes() = ['10.2.110.1', '10.2.25.65', '10.2.94.87', '10.2.20.209', '10.2.6.206', '10.2.94.55', '10.2.182.10', '10.2.94.86', '10.2.20.2', '10.2.20.1', '10.2.94.94']

G.edges() = [('10.2.110.1', '10.2.20.2'), ('10.2.110.1', '10.2.20.1'), ('10.2.25.65', '10.2.6.206'), ('10.2.94.87', '10.2.94.55'), ('10.2.20.209', '10.2.110.1'), ('10.2.94.55', '10.2.20.209'), ('10.2.182.10', '10.2.182.10'), ('10.2.94.86', '10.2.94.87'), ('10.2.20.2', '10.2.25.65'), ('10.2.20.1', '10.2.182.10'), ('10.2.94.94', '10.2.94.86')]
```

That above, produces the following topology.
[image]

As you can see, `node_94` is green, because is the starting node. Both `node_10` and `node_206` are the farEnds.

I want to remove nodes from the graph depending on the number of hops away from the farEnds for `node_94`.

I have this function which tries to remove nodes depending on how far a node is from a given farEnd.

```
def getHopToNH(G):

labelList   = {}
nodes       = G

for startNode in nodes.nodes():

    try:
        farInt = nx.get_node_attributes(nodes,'farInt')[startNode]
    except:
        farInt = 'NA'

    try:
        p = min([len(nx.shortest_path(nodes,source=startNode,target=end)) for end in farInt])
    except:
        p = 0

    if p < 7:
        labelList = {**labelList,**{str(startNode):'node_'+str(startNode).split(".")[3]}}
    else:
        nodes.remove_node(startNode)

return labelList,nodes
```

However, when running that function, I get the following error:

```
  File "trace_1_7.py", line 87, in getHopToNH
    for startNode in nodes.nodes():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

The problem arises with the `nodes.remove_node(startNode)`. If I remove that line, the code works nice and produces the plot that you can see above.

How can I accomplish the removal based on the number of hops towards a farEnd?

Thanks!

Lucas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `networkx` internally represents graphs using `dict`s, when iterating over a graph's nodes, we are iterating over the keys of a dictionary (this dictionary maps each node to its attributes). Using `remove_node` will change the size of this dictionary, which is not allowed when we are iterating over its key, hence the `RuntimeError`.

To remove nodes, we maintain a list containing the nodes we want to remove, then remove the nodes in this list after the `for` loop.

```
def getHopToNH(G):

    labelList   = {}
    nodes       = G
    nodes_to_remove = []

    for startNode in nodes.nodes():

        try:
            farInt = nx.get_node_attributes(nodes,'farInt')[startNode]
        except:
            farInt = 'NA'

        try:
            p = min([len(nx.shortest_path(nodes,source=startNode,target=end)) for end in farInt])
        except:
            p = 0

        if p < 7:
            labelList = {**labelList,**{str(startNode):'node_'+str(startNode).split(".")[3]}}
        else:
            nodes_to_remove.append(startNode)

    nodes.remove_nodes_from(nodes_to_remove)

    return labelList,nodes
```

Comment: Very easy: how come I did not see it! ... :-) ... Thank you very much!